# Наложение шейпов в канвасе

Tags: javascript, canvas, math

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким методом в канвасе отловить когда две фигуры пересеклись?

Comment: Как бы по координатам в двухмерном пространстве. Если с математикой в школе институте имел дело, то составляется уравнение прямых и приравниваются, если решения есть, значит пересекаются, если нет, значит не пересекаются)

Comment: А что понимается под пересчением? Пересчение ребер или же площадей? Если первое, то вариант сверху, если второе, то можно задать область одной из фигур неравенствами (читай условями) и сравнить с ними координаты точек второй фигуры. Если хоть одна попала, то пересечение имеется. А вообще приложите свой код для получения конструктивного ответа.

Comment: Спасибо, уже разобрался, просто рассчитывал на нативный метод, но оказалось что без математики никак.